# Ocultar Boton al cerrrar Formulario

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, windows, visual-studio-2017

Hola chico@s he intenrtado de muchas maneras y no lo logro conseguir

Necesito de su ayuda, lo que necesito es que el boton **inscripcion** aparezca cuando la ventana inscripcion se habra y que el boton se oculte cuando se cierre la ventana inscripcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi como esta imagen, en este imagen se encuentran abiertas las ventanas edicion de productos, devolucion y salida de inventario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo que prodria ser recorriendo los form abiertos con  `application.OpenForm`  pero no encuentro la manera de como programarlo

Comment: Debes poner el codigo que llevas hasta ahora, el que tiene que ver con el problema que tienes

Comment: hasta ahora no llevo nada de codigo en lo que expongo, solamente tengo codigo en las otras ventanas pero muy aparte lo que solicito